# Multiple redux-form reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Is it possible to create multiple redux-forms reducers? 
for example I would like the application state to look like this:

```
activities: {
    login: {
        form: {
            // ... all login form data
        }
        // ... more login data
    },
    customer: {
        form: {
            // ... all customer form data
        }
        // ... more customer data
    }
}
```

so basically, is it possible to connect a form component to a specific reducer or always works with a single reducer and only the form names are dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's possible but in such case you have to tell given redux-form decorator where corresponding reducer was mounted. There is a `getFormState` config property in `reduxForm` which expects function that according to docs:

> ..takes the entire Redux state and returns the state
>   slice which corresponds to where the redux-form reducer was mounted.
>   This functionality is rarely needed, and defaults to assuming that the
>   reducer is mounted under the form key

So since you can define reducer for given form you can use multiple reducers.

For more details check [redux-form reducer](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Reducer.md/) and [reduxForm decorator](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/),

Answer (score -1):

USE combineReducers or this pattern :

```
    const recipeReducers  = (recipes , action) =>{   //recipes --- state.recipes
        switch (action.type) {
            case action_type.ADD_RECIPE:{
                return  recipes.concat({name: action.name})
                };
            default:
                return recipes

        }
    }
    const ingredientsReducer = (ingredients, action) =>{
        switch (action.type) {
            case action_type.ADD_INGREDIENT:{
                const newIngredient = {
                    name: action.name,
                    recipe: action.recipe,
                    quantity: action.quantity
                };
                return ingredients.concat(newIngredient)
                };
            default:
                return ingredients
        }
    }


    const reducer = (state={}, action) => {
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
             recipes: recipeReducers(state.recipes, action),
             ingredients: ingredientsReducer(state.ingredients, action)
        });
     };



const initialState = {
         recipes: [
                         {
                             name: 'Omelette'
                        }
                ],
     ingredients: [
                     {
                        recipe: 'Omelette',
                     name: 'Egg',
                     quantity: 2
                 }
     ]
 };



function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
    const store = createStore(
        reducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
    return store;
};
window.store = configureStore(initialState);
store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))
```